# Auto-repeating AJAX function doesn't work

Tags: ajax, auto-update

I'm looking to repeat this function every five seconds:

```
  function check_votes(id) {  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'check_votes.php',
            data: 'checkvotes='+id,
            timeout: 0,
          success: function(data) {
          window.setTimeout(check_votes(id), 5000);
            $('.vote_count_'+id).show();
            $('.vote_count_'+id).html("("+data+" votes so far)");
          }
        });
        return false;
  };
```

Why doesn't this line do the trick:

```
 window.setTimeout(check_votes(id), 5000);
```

In fact, it breaks it, so I need to use the following line:

```
 window.setTimeout(check_votes, 5000);
```

But that allows for the script to run initially, but I get no auto-repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setTimeout(check_votes(id), 5000);
```

is wrong because `check_votes(id)` immediately invokes the function, whereas the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method expects you to pass it a function pointer as first argument.

```
window.setTimeout(check_votes, 5000);
```

is wrong because you are not passing the `check_votes` function the id parameter and I guess your AJAX call crashes as it's missing it.

So try the following:

```
window.setTimeout(check_votes, 5000, id);
```

Notice how we are passing the `id` parameter to the `check_votes` callback.

You can pass an arbitrary number of arguments using this overload:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this in an "anonymous function"

```
window.setTimeout(function(){check_votes(id)}, 5000);
```